# CSV Export from Bigquery having columns surrounded with double quotes adding not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, export-to-csv, spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery

I am trying to export a table as CSV file in GCS bucket from Google Big Query console with export command, but facing issues with double quotes.

I want to export as csv but every column value should be surrounded with double quotes, i tried using various String functions such as FORMAT, CONCAT, REPLACE etc, but not able to get desired results.

I am trying to export as csv because only these formats are supported by Export command (CSV, JSON, Parquet, Avro) , even a plain text file is fine for me, but don't have that option and i need columns surrounded by double quotes and delimited by comma.

this is export command:

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS( uri='gs://bucket-name123/SOME-FILE-*', format='CSV', overwrite=true, header=false, field_delimiter=',')
AS
SELECT CONCAT('\"',column1,'\"'), CONCAT('\"',column2,'\"') from `projectId.datasetId.TABLE_NAME` where column3 = true;
```

Data is getting exported successfully in GCS bucket , but i am getting 3 double quotes surrounding this column instead of 1 double quotes:

content of GCS exported GCS file is as below:

```
"""value1""","""AAA""""
"""value2""","""BBB""""
"""value3""","""CCC""""
```

I am expecting this content format:

```
"value1","AAA"
"value2","BBB"
```

Any help or hint will be appreciated,

I have also tried `FORMAT('%s',column1)` -- this function, but it also produces 3 double quotes

I also tried to hit EXPORT query as a job from Java Google BQ api, but same result.

I can't use "bq extract" because i want to only export limited columns, and extract don't have functionality to export limited columns, it exports whole table.

Comment: Why do you need the double quote? Do you have comma in the text field? did you consider other separator instead?

Comment: I can't change the output file, this exported file will be consumed by downstream system as it is, and they need this specific format only:
"row1-value1","row1-value2"

Comment: If you need a specific format, it's not CSV, it's CSV-like, and you need a specific process to match your specific format

Comment: apology for mising out that. Yes i need CSV like format, it's not CSV, i need columns surrounded by double quotes and delimited by comma, and file without any extension.
But, since EXPORT don't support format=none, i am using format=CSV

Comment: You can either post process the file and adapt it, or have a process that query the data and directly write the expected output format. I'm bad at Spark, but if you have skill with this, you should have a try at spark serverless to achieve that.

Comment: i thought of processing the file and writing to bucket, but this file size can be maximum 2GB , so processing this much of huge data in application will need high memory, and if i process in batch of some records then it will take few mins to complete the process

Answer (score 0):

Don't add double quotes yourself. When you export to CSV from BigQuery, double quotes are added automatically, if they are needed, e.g. for multi-line strings and escaping double quotes (which is why you are seeing repeated double quotes in your output)

So you command should simply be:

```sql
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri='gs://bucket-name123/SOME-FILE-*', 
  format='CSV',
  overwrite=true,
  header=false,
  field_delimiter=',')
AS SELECT column1, column2 from projectId.datasetId.TABLE_NAME
WHERE column3 = true;
```

Most CSV readers will be able to read the output format.

Comment: apology for missing out in proper description. 
i need CSV like format, it's not CSV, i need columns surrounded by double quotes and delimited by comma, and file without any extension. But, since EXPORT don't support format=none, i am using format=CSV
is there a way to export a file with that specific format?

Comment: @VikramKumar I don't think so, no. In that case, I would recommend adding another processing step after the export so you can get the file into the format you need, similar to what guillaume blaquiere suggests in your comment thread above